# Post multiple image using share extension in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

I want to share or post multiple image in my app using my app share extension.
Currently I am using below code.

```
for (NSItemProvider* itemProvider in ((NSExtensionItem*)self.extensionContext.inputItems[0]).attachments ) {

    if([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.png"]) {
        NSLog(@"itemprovider = %@", itemProvider);

        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.png" options:nil completionHandler: ^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error) {

            NSData *imgData;
            if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
                imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)item];
            }
            if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
            {

                //imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((UIImage*)item, 1.0);
                imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage*)item);
            }

            NSDictionary *dict = @{
                                   @"imgData" : imgData,
                                   @"name" : self.contentText
                                   };
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.example”];
            [defaults setObject:dict forKey:@"img"];
            [defaults synchronize];


            [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[]
                                               completionHandler:nil];

        }];

    }
}
```

How I can post multiple image and what changes I have to do in post code.
Happy Coding :) waiting for some positive response.

Comment: Any one have any answer or suggestion for this?

Comment: Please help me if you know about how to implement this feature in Xamarin Ios.

Comment: I am implemented this in iOS,Not sure about Xamarin.

Comment: I'm also using Xamarin Ios..

Comment: means using objective C and Swift, you can follow same logic in Xamarin I dont think so there is any difference, only code in C#

Comment: If you don't mind would you please assist me how to develop it. Because I have tried lots but all are failed

Comment: what you tried, can you describe in chat